# rewriting URL (file) extension on IIS7

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

My company's site in in Classic ASP (`.asp` extension)
Is it possible to change the files to `.htm` (or something else), but still have IIS parse them as ASP files?

```
Using Windows Web Server 2008 R2
and IIS 7.5
Host says that URL Rewrite module version is 2.0 on the server.
```

Thank you.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with mod-rewrite, so you should remove the tag. Possible if you create a correct rewrite rule.

Comment: @LexLi thanks, removed. I guess that's what I'm asking for - what would this rule look like?

Comment: You might get some ideas from posts like https://www.saotn.org/iis-url-rewrite-hide-php-extension/

Comment: Very helpful, Thank you @LexLi- if you can post this as the answer i will sign it off.

Comment: I just showed you the approach. You should post your rule as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

h/t @Lex Li:

```
<rule name="hide .asp extension" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
<conditions>
  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.asp" matchType="IsFile" />
</conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.asp" />
</rule>
```